# query having a function wait until user has clicked yes or cancel

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a bunch of items, I created a function to delete a row, but would like to use a modal to confirm the user actually wants to delete a row.

My delete function is as follows:

```
var removeFootable_row = function() {
    var $this, $currentFooTable, $currentTable, $currentRow;
    $this = $(this);
    $currentFooTable = $this.parents("table").data("footable");
    $currentTable = $this.parents("table");
    $currentRow = $this.parents("tr");

    $("#confirm-modal").modal("show");


    // I WANT TO PAUSE HERE AND ONLY CONTINUE IF THE USER CLICKS THE YES BUTTON


    $currentRow.animate({opacity:0},{
        duration:150,
        queue:false,
        complete:function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $currentFooTable.removeRow($currentRow);
            }, 250);
        }   
    });
};
```

I read a little about promises and deferred, but I'm really not sure what the best way to do this is, any ideas?  Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Bind a click event handler to the "Yes" button and put the `animate` call there.

Comment: What plugin implement `modal`?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap for the modal

Comment: I'm concerned about loosing my this references

Answer (score 1):

Another user already gave you the answer. You have to split your functions like this.

```
// Global variable
var $rowToDelete;

function askUserConfirmation() {
    var $this, $currentFooTable, $currentTable, $currentRow;
    $this = $(this);
    $currentFooTable = $this.parents("table").data("footable");
    $currentTable = $this.parents("table");
    $currentRow = $this.parents("tr");
    $rowToDelete = $currentRow;
    $("#confirm-modal").modal("show");
}
```

This will show your modal asking to confirm. Now, attach to the "Okay" button the function to actually remove the row. (Since you didn't post any code about your modal window I will user my own ids. You will have to change them for yours)

```
function removeFootableRow() {
     $rowToDelete.animate({opacity:0},{
         duration:150,
         queue:false,
         complete:function() {
             setTimeout(function() {
                 $currentFooTable.removeRow($currentRow);
             }, 250);
         }   
     });
}
```

And attach the function to your button. HTML:

```
<!-- "Okay" button of your modal -->
<input type="button" id="btnDeleteRow" />
```

Using JQuery to attach it:

```
$('#btnDeleteRow').off('click');
$('#btnDeleteRow').on('click', function () {
    removeFootableRow();
});
```

And that's it. This will work.